# Can I simultaneously plot 2 vectors on a single Bloch sphere and rotate the angle of visualization?

Tags: programming, qiskit, bloch-sphere

I'm trying to plot 2 vectors on the same Bloch sphere. From the qiskit documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_bloch_vector.html), we can find `plot_bloch_vector(bloch, title='', ax=None, figsize=None, coord_type='cartesian')`. So I'm not quite sure if we could plot 2 vectors (say `[0,0,1]` and `[0,1,0]`) on the same Bloch sphere.

Also, from the default visualization angle, some vectors might look like they're overlapping with the x-axis (e.g the figure below). Can I switch to another angle to visualize the sphere?

[image]

Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a Jupyter notebook, you can use kaleidoscope for that. It has a `block_sphere` function that does exactly that. See [the documentation for more info](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_bloch_vector.html). To install it `pip install kaleidoscope`.

You can set several vectors in the sphere that can be rotated with the mouse.

```
from kaleidoscope import bloch_sphere

bloch_sphere([[0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that works really great:)

Comment: This made my day!  I'd been trying to use matplotlib figures and axis and I was struggling to say the least.  This made it so easy!  Will be exploring Kaleidescope further!